# Unable to update my PC - error 0x80244022

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Since November 2019 I'm unable to update my PC. Windows update give me the error 0x80244022

At the moment I download and install the update from Microsoft Update Catalog.

Windows is licenced and the control panel say is active.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide the relevant information from [Setupdiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag).

Comment: This error occurs when there is a conflict with dedicated software updates. Try the steps in the Windows Update Troubleshooter and that will likely resolve your issues .  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: If the previous suggestions do not resolve the issue, please issue the following in an Admin terminal and in the order listed: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot > Retry update

Comment: Thank you @JeffZeitlin you save me the day!

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing Error Code 80244022 when trying to run Windows Update on either a workstation or server then it’s likely that computer had its  updates deployed via WSUS or a similar patch deployment platform.

From time to time the link between the computer and the patch deployment management service will break triggering Error Code 80244022 whenever you try and check for new updates from the desktop of the computer.

[How to fix Windows Update Error Code 80244022](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/deployment/update/waas-manage-updates-wsus)

If Windows Updates is no longer being managed by WSUS or a similar platform then the fix is rather easy.

Open registry editor by clicking Start menu –> Run and typing regedit – click OK

Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

Modify the value of UseWUServer and change it from 1 to 0. The zero disables Windows Updates from using WSUS.

Now go into Services.msc and restart the Windows Update Service.
You should now be able to check for new available Windows Updates.

Comment: Link is dead. Anyone got a section of text to replace the link with?

Comment: In my case the culprit was a WSUS server issue (service was running but application pool in IIS was stopped). Once fixed the WSUS issue, the update check worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

If Windows Updates is still being managed by WSUS, then the fix is rather easy as well:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
net stop dosvc
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
wuauclt /reportnow
wuauclt /detectnow
```